# What happens if a bot is not able to answer?

Tags: chatbot, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

In the main QnA website, if I make a question which has no answer, I get an answer as:

> I don’t have an answer for that. Try typing MENU to go back to the main menu

That's ok, because sometimes the knowledge database is still in the learning stage. But how can I access these questions that have no answer so that I can improve my bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the docs for QnA Maker say,

> QnA Maker stores all chat logs and other telemetry, if you have
>   enabled App Insights during the [creation of your QnA Maker service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/set-up-qnamaker-service-azure).
>   Run the sample queries to get your chat logs from App Insights.

See [Analytics on your knowledge base](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/how-to/get-analytics-knowledge-base) for details on how to implement and run queries on the analytics gathered.

[image]